# How to sort a file contents after n lines?

Tags: sort, text

In linux we can run `sort` command to sort file contents, but in my case I have the following file (THANKS.txt):

```
These people have contributed to OSN Envoy. We always try to keep this list updated and correct. 
If you notice that your name is not listed here, then feel free to contact us.

Ar Rakin
Peter Williamson
David Brook
Bill Natt
```

This file contains the list of the contributors of a software project.

I want to ONLY sort the names alphabetically using the `sort` command, any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
  NR == 1, NF == 0 {
    # print and skip all lines until the first blank
    # one (one where the Number of Fields is 0)
    print; next
  } 

  {print | "sort"} # pass the rest to sort
  ' < file
```

Replace `NF == 0` with `NR == 3` to stop at the third line instead of upon the first blank one.

To avoid having the rest go through both `awk` and `sort` (and also avoid the extra shell run by `awk` to interpret that trivial `sort` command line), you could do:

```
{
  sed '/[^[:blank:]]/!q'
  sort
} < file
```

Where `sed` `q`uits upon finding the first line that does not (`!`) contain a non-blank character. Change to `sed 3q` to `q`uit at the third line.

If the input is not seekable (like when it's coming from a pipe), `sed` will however not be able to leave the cursor within the file just after the delimiter of that line though, which means `sort` will miss the extra data that `sed` may have read (as it reads its input in largish blocks).

With the GNU implementation of `sed`, you can add the `-u` option for it to read its input one byte at a time so as not to read too much.

Answer (score 3):

This would give you just the list of names, sorted:

```bsh
sed '1,/^$/d' <THANKS.txt | sort
```

The pipeline uses `sed` to delete everything from the first line to the first empty line and passes the rest to `sort` for sorting. You may also use the line number of the empty line in place of the regular expression address `/^$/`, both above and in the other commands in this answer, if that is easier.

The initial part of the document could be had by

```bsh
sed '1,/^$/!d' <THANKS.txt
```

That command essentially inverts the condition for the `d` command is `sed` so that it deletes the list of names rather than extracting the list of names.

Together, these two command could be used to solve the overall issue, creating the `THANKS-sorted.txt` output file:

```bsh
{ sed '1,/^$/!d' <THANKS.txt; sed '1,/^$/d' <THANKS.txt | sort; } >THANKS-sorted.txt
```

Or, with nicer formatting:

```bsh
{
    sed '1,/^$/!d' <THANKS.txt
    sed '1,/^$/ d' <THANKS.txt | sort
} >THANKS-sorted.txt
```

---

With the `ed` editor:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' '1,/^$/ p' '+,$ w !sort' 'q' | ed -s THANKS.txt >THANKS-sorted.txt
```

This uses an `ed` editing script that looks like this:

```
1,/^$/ p
+,$ w !sort
q
```

This editing script outputs the first few lines, up until the first blank line.  It then writes all lines from the next line after the blank line to the end of the document to `sort`, which outputs the sorted names.

The final `q` exits the editor, and the redirection at the end writes the resulting text to `THANKS-sorted.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

If the `head` command doesn't close `stdin` (it doesn't on linux), try

```
{ head -n2; sort; } < file
These people have contributed to OSN Envoy. We always try to keep this list updated and correct. 
If you notice that your name is not listed here, then feel free to contact us.

Ar Rakin
Bill Natt
David Brook
Peter Williamson
```

If stdin is closed by `head`, try something like

```
{ read TMP; echo "$TMP"; read TMP; echo "$TMP"; sort; } < file
These people have contributed to OSN Envoy. We always try to keep this list updated and correct.
If you notice that your name is not listed here, then feel free to contact us.

Ar Rakin
Bill Natt
David Brook
Peter Williamson
```

Comment: It's not about `head` closing its input. Of course it closes its input as it terminates. But about it reading past the second newline character. All `head` implementations will likely read past the second newline as they read by blocks, but POSIX compliant ones will seek back to just after that newline character if the input is seekable.

Comment: See also [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123) and [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas great comment. I was wondering why `cat file | ( head -n2; sort;)` did not work but `( head -n2; sort;) < file` did.